# Cannot connect to Wifi on Linux Mint Version 4.15.0-45

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, laptop, hp

Fresh install of Linux Mint but I cannot connect to my wifi. I have used an ethernet to install all automatic updates and such that come with the fresh install.

`ifconfig` gives out:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.168  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2a00:23c5:709a:7701:d528:6c9c:a5db:8209  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a00:23c5:709a:7701:f33:ead7:1be5:7832  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::b4dd:a9b3:46e3:d6a2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e4:e7:49:3e:f4:da  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4901  bytes 2907253 (2.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 5  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4578  bytes 649717 (649.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1361  bytes 126333 (126.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1361  bytes 126333 (126.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`iwconfig` gives:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

`rfkill list all` gives:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

My Laptop is:

HP Pavilion - 14-ce0508na

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the WiFi chipset working/build the necessary kernel mode, run in the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential dkms
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Reboot.

From HP Forums [No WIFI presence on Ubuntu 16.04](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/No-WIFI-presence-on-Ubuntu-16-04/td-p/6633337)

The DKMS here in these instructions is a good idea, as it will automatically compile and install this module on any new kernel version installed. e.g. this module will be present on future kernel updates as long it is compatible with the version of the new installed kernel.

Comment: Do not forget to select it as the correct answer using the checkmark on the left.